# Gradle Eclipse filter non wanted fiiles from root

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-tool-suite

I use eclipse 4.4 and the Gradle plugin. If I do an import gradle operation from eclipse I can 
see that the subporjects folders are filtered out. Unfortunatly this is not enough for me because I have source files that are placed under the root project, but outside the subprojects folder (for legacy reasons). So for instance:

```
 root
 --- src
     --- one-sources    
     --- two-sources
 --- one
 --- two
 --- random-folder
 --- random-file
```

Now if I open the root project plus its subprojects in Eclipse all files under src are found twice on a navigation (once for the root, second for the subproject). Any ways to fix this?

Second I have some other random files under the root that I want to exclude from the Eclipse project automatically. Any ways to achieve this?

I have tried writing it with gradle script:

```
// -------- Eclipse support ------------------------------
eclipse {
project {
    buildCommand 'build'
    file {
        withXml { xmlProvider ->
            def addFilterMatcher = {Node to, String path ->
                Node matcher = to.appendNode('matcher')
                matcher.appendNode("id", "org.eclipse.ui.ide.multiFilter")
                matcher.appendNode("arguments", "1.0-projectRelativePath-equals-true-false-" + path)
            }
            Node project = xmlProvider.asNode()
            Node filter = project.appendNode('filteredResources').appendNode('filter')
            filter.appendNode('id', new Date().getTime())
            filter.appendNode('name', 'filter subprojects source code')
            filter.appendNode('type', 10)
            Node orNode = filter.appendNode('matcher')
            orNode.appendNode('id', 'org.eclipse.ui.ide.orFilterMatcher')
            Node orArgs = orNode.appendNode('arguments')
            addFilterMatcher(orArgs, "api2")
            addFilterMatcher(orArgs, "AnnotationProcessor")
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that, it does not work. It is added to the relevant .project section. However, from within Eclipse I cannot see it (but is there alongside the subproject entries):

```
<filteredResources>
    <filter>
        <id>1409147301041</id>
        <name></name>
        <type>26</type>
        <matcher>
            <id>org.eclipse.ui.ide.orFilterMatcher</id>
            <arguments>
                <matcher>
                    <id>org.eclipse.ui.ide.multiFilter</id>
                    <arguments>1.0-projectRelativePath-equals-true-false-one</arguments>
                </matcher>
            </arguments>
        </matcher>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <id>1409147300428</id>
        <name>filter subprojects source code</name>
        <type>10</type>
        <matcher>
            <id>org.eclipse.ui.ide.orFilterMatcher</id>
            <arguments>
                <matcher>
                    <id>org.eclipse.ui.ide.multiFilter</id>
                    <arguments>1.0-projectRelativePath-equals-true-false-random-stuff</arguments>
                </matcher>
            </arguments>
        </matcher>
    </filter>
</filteredResources>
```

Thanks,

Comment: `withXml` only takes effect when generating Eclipse files with `gradle eclipse`, *instead* of using the Eclipse Gradle integration. Alternatively, it should also be possible to configure further filters via the Eclipse UI (although I don't fully understand your problem description).

Comment: the withXml is run as part of the gradle import, and the content is added to the file (although the import operation does generate extra entries too, it also adds what I added).

Comment: Right, it's run if the import is configured to run the `eclipse` task. Anyway, try if the file generation approach makes a difference.